# Agreement between 'a lot of' + 2 uncountable nouns and the predicate

Tags: verb-agreement, uncountable-nouns

Which of the following is correct?

> 1. "A lot of paper and cardboard is recycled"
> 2. "A lot of paper and cardboard are recycled"?

It feels like the 1st sentence is correct, because we see the two materials as a whole, but I' m not sure.

Comment: I agree: the first sentence is the one I would prefer.  However, "A lot of paper and a lot of cardboard are recycled" would also be acceptable.

Comment: Replace *lot* with *box* and the reason will be more obvious.

Answer (score -1):

The first sentence is correct:  "lot" is the subject of the sentence and is singular.  "Is" agrees with it.  "Paper and cardboard" are objects of the preposition "of" and modify the subject "lot."